# Robocopy - create a log file with only successful file transfers

Tags: logging, robocopy

I'm trying to accomplish 2 things and I'm not sure the best way.

1. copy new or modified files from a windows source to another windows server and log the transaction (completed and logged using Robocopy), e.g.:

   ROBOCOPY /XO /XX /Z /V /BYTES /LOG:\ServerB\Log.txt \ServerA\source \ServerB\target *.txt /A-:A
2. create a simple list (control file for another process) of just the file names that were copied above, to a new file without any of the other details, e.g.:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

I considered running the Robocopy statement twice, once with /L and writing it to a log then running the same statement without /L and writing it to a log to get what I need but I haven't been able to find a way to generate a simple log file with only the successful file names (like example above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite clear whether you only want to have the copied files in the log or even the non-copied same files.
You can omit the /Verbose option, then you do not need to hide as many states.
Do you need this log to create the list for the other process or is it intended for the documentation?

If the LOG is intended for the documentation, then you can rattling everything without option /L in a loop.

```
setlocal
for /f "delims= " %%t in ('robocopy . . /njh /njs')do set "tab=%%t"
3>controlfile (
  for /f "tokens=3 delims=%tab%" %%i in ('robocopy /xx /xo /Z /bytes \\ServerA\source \\ServerB\target *.txt /tee /LOG:\\ServerB\Log.txt
  ') do >&3 echo %%i
)
```

Comment: The log example that I supplied with verbose logging is required for documentation.  The list of files copied (new and modified) is required for another process to pick-up, which is why I considered robocopy statement twice, with the first run including /L.  Since running a robocopy command twice would not produce the same results, I want to try out your suggestion with a /L and without the /V.  Thanks for your advice!  I'll try it soon

Comment: after a couple minor changes, I got this working exactly how I needed.  Thanks!  This is a non-specific version of the code I used:

Comment: `SETLOCAL
FOR /F "DELIMS= " %%t IN ('ROBOCOPY . . /NJH /NJS') DO SET "tab=%%t"
3>controlFile.txt (
 FOR /F "TOKENS=3 DELIMS=%tab%" %%i IN ('ROBOCOPY /XX /XO /Z /BYTES /L \\ServerA\source \\ServerB\target *.txt
  ') DO >&3 ECHO %%i
)

ROBOCOPY /XO /XX /Z /V /BYTES /LOG:\\ServerB\LOG.txt \\ServerA\source \\ServerB\target *.txt /A-:A`